# The sum of the first n terms of an arithmetic sequence is $1440$. If the first term of the sequence is $-7$ and the $n$th term is $71$, what is $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic sequence is $1440$. If the first term of the
>   sequence is $-7$ and the nth term is $71$, what is $n$ ?

I had no clue on how to solve this but I was thinking in the lines of the following:

$$-7+(-7+d)+(-7+2d).... +71$$

and $71$ is basically equal to $(-7+d(n-1))$, in which I would like some assistance

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$1440=\dfrac n2(-7+71)$$

as the sum of $n$ terms of an Arithmetic Series is $$\dfrac{n\{2a+(n-1)d\}}2=\dfrac{n(a+l)}2$$

where $l=a+(n-1)d$ is the last term, $a$ is the first term & $d$ is the common difference.

Answer (score 2):

Sum($S$) of $n$ terms of Arithmetic Progression is given by

$$S=\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$$
which is according to the question
$$1440=\frac{n(-7+71)}{2}$$